# CIDepthBlurEffect Failed to render part of the image because of the memory requirement

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

CIDepthBlurEffect normally works on my phone with ios 12.4 but it gives the following errors when I try to examine "inputFocusRect" parameter? Also no error is produced when I set y : 0; however image is not processed. Any idea? Thanks.

- Failed to render 12192768 pixels because a CIKernel's ROI function did not allow tiling.
- Failed to render part of the image because memory requirement of -1 too big.

Here is the code:

```swift
if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIDepthBlurEffect", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey : mainImage, kCIInputDisparityImageKey : disparityMap])   {

    filter.setValue(0.1, forKey: "inputAperture")
    filter.setValue(0.1, forKey: "inputScaleFactor")
    filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 100, z: 100, w: 100), forKey: "inputFocusRect") // works without this line

    let result = filter.outputImage
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: result!)
}
```

Comment: (1) Blur _is_ memory intensive. You cannot blur a big image this way. (2) `self.imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: result!)` is not a proper way to turn a CIImage into a UIImage for display.

Comment: What is the proper way then?

Comment: Also note that when I only blur background without touching "inputFocusRect", it works?!

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe not *the* solution, but I noticed two things that you could try and report back the results:

- As matt pointed out, you should properly *render* the image first before using it in an image view. You need a `CIContext` for that (see below).
- There seem to be a special constructor for the depth blur effect filter that is also linked to a `CIContext`.

Here's some could you can try:

```
// create this only once and re-use it when possible, it's an expensive object
let ciContext = CIContext()

let filter = ciContext.depthBlurEffectFilter(for: mainImage, 
                                             disparityImage: disparityMap, 
                                             portraitEffectsMatte: nil, 
                                             // the orientation of you input image
                                             orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.up,
                                             options: nil)!
filter.setValue(0.1, forKey: "inputAperture")
filter.setValue(0.1, forKey: "inputScaleFactor")
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 100, z: 100, w: 100), forKey: "inputFocusRect")

let result = ciContext.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, from: mainImage.extent)
self.imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: result)
```

Would be interesting to hear if this helps in any way.

Comment: Thank you Frank. Helpful you again). I just tried your code but it didn't worked,too. same errors again.

Comment: That's unfortunate. On what device are you testing? And can you tell me what `inputFocusRect` does? I couldn't find any documentation...

Comment: Also, please test your app as release build on your device without any debugger attached. The Metal debugger and profiler adds a lot of overhead at runtime sometimes.

Comment: I dont know what the inputFocusRect does (although I guess it focuses on the selected area better or opposite). I am trying - playing with the depth API for now.